# Vite Configure Absolut Import Paths Gives Styelint Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I am attempting to set up the Vite project configuration shown in Thomas Findlay's book "React The Road To Enterprise." I am trying to configure absolute imports (2.2.7)

When I run `pnpm run dev` or `npm run dev` the dev server gives this error referencing `stylelint`. Does anyone know what the issue could be? All my config files are below. (https://github.com/currenthandle/react-road-to-enterprise)

```
error when starting dev server:
Error: Dynamic require of "stylelint" is not supported
    at formatError (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:39975:46)
    at Context.error (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:39971:19)
    at Context.buildStart (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite-plugin-stylelint@3.0.2_ob6wbqjaxhaqcketchi7ll2j5i/node_modules/vite-plugin-stylelint/dist/index.mjs:1:2251)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async hookParallel (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:39862:9)
    at async Object.buildStart (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:40133:13)
    at async file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:61879:13
    at async httpServer.listen (file:///Users/casey/Dev/react-the-road-to-enterprise/node_modules/.pnpm/vite@3.2.4_ajklay5k626t46b6fyghkbup3i/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-67e7f8ab.js:61894:17)
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

https://github.com/currenthandle/react-road-to-enterprise

`vite.config.ts`

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';
import StylelintPlugin from 'vite-plugin-stylelint';
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    eslint(),
    StylelintPlugin({
      fix: true,
      quiet: false,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      'test-utils': fileURLToPath(
        new URL('./src/helpers/test-utils.tsx', import.meta.url)
      ),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        // example : additionalData: `@import "./src/styles/variables";`
        // There is need to include the .scss file extensions.
        additionalData: `@import "./src/styles/variables";`,
      },
    },
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'json', 'html'],
    },
    setupFiles: ['./vitest.setup.ts'],
  },
});
```

`tsconfig.ts`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "test-utils": ["src/helpers/test-utils"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`stylelint.config.cjs`

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard',
    'stylelint-config-recess-order',
    'stylelint-config-css-modules',
    'stylelint-config-prettier',
    // Uncomment out the below if you want to use scss
    'stylelint-config-standard-scss',
    'stylelint-config-recommended-scss',
  ],
  plugins: ['stylelint-scss'],
  ignoreFiles: [
    './node_modules/**/*.css',
    './dist/**/*.css',
    './coverage/**/*.css',
  ],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: [
          'tailwind',
          'apply',
          'screen',
          'variants',
          'responsive',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'no-duplicate-selectors': null,
    'no-empty-source': null,
    'rule-empty-line-before': null,
    'comment-empty-line-before': null,
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': null,
    'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
    'no-descending-specificity': null,
    'string-no-newline': null,
    // Limit the number of universal selectors in a selector,
    // to avoid very slow selectors
    'selector-max-universal': 1,
    'selector-class-pattern': '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$',
    // --------
    // SCSS rules
    // --------
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-before': 'never',
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-after': 'always',
    'scss/dollar-variable-no-missing-interpolation': true,
    'scss/dollar-variable-pattern': /^[a-z-]+$/,
    'scss/double-slash-comment-whitespace-inside': 'always',
    'scss/operator-no-newline-before': true,
    'scss/operator-no-unspaced': true,
    'scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector': true,
    // Allow SCSS and CSS module keywords beginning with `@`
    'scss/at-rule-no-unknown': null,
  },
}
```

`postcss.config.cjs`

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('stylelint')({
      configFile: 'stylelint.config.js',
    }),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-extend'),
    require('postcss-mixins'),
    // Comment out postcss-nested if you're using tailwindcss/nesting
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss')('tailwind.config.js'),
    require('postcss-preset-env', {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009',
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        'custom-properties': false,
        'nesting-rules': false,
      },
    }),
    require('autoprefixer')(),
    require('postcss-reporter'),
  ],
};
```

`tailwind.config.cjs`

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  // Add only if you want to use the @tailwindcss/forms package
  plugins: [require('@tailwindcss/forms')],
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "test-utils": ["src/helpers/test-utils"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

`postcss.config.cjs`

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('stylelint')({
      configFile: 'stylelint.config.js',
    }),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-extend'),
    require('postcss-mixins'),
    // Comment out postcss-nested if you're using tailwindcss/nesting
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
    require('tailwindcss')('tailwind.config.js'),
    require('postcss-preset-env', {
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009',
      },
      stage: 3,
      features: {
        'custom-properties': false,
        'nesting-rules': false,
      },
    }),
    require('autoprefixer')(),
    require('postcss-reporter'),
  ],
};
```

`prettier.config.cjs`

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  endOfLine: 'lf',
  jsxSingleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 80,
  proseWrap: 'never',
  quoteProps: 'as-needed',
  semi: true,
  singleQuote: true,
  tabWidth: 2,
  trailingComma: 'es5',
  useTabs: false,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `type: "module"` from package.json file. This may help.

Answer (score 0):

I sent you an email with an explanation for this issue and how to fix it. I also created a PR in your repo. I will briefly explain here why the problem happened and how to fix it for anyone who runs into it in the future.

Vite 3 does something that Vite 2 doesn't. It automatically sets the "type" property in the "package.json" file to "module". So, one way to fix the problem mentioned by the OP is to either remove it or set it to "commonjs". But why does this problem happen in the first place? It turns out that vite-plugin-stylelint@3.0.2 doesn't work correctly when the "type" is set to "module". This problem was fixed in version 3.0.3, so the solution is to install newer versions than 3.0.2.